# Circular listview android

Tags: android, listview

Im working on my circular list view. I implement almost all functionality, but i have some problem. When my activity starts my listView looks like: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44444463/Screenshot_2013-02-28-14-37-17.png

But it is not right. It should looks like: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44444463/Screenshot_2013-02-28-14-37-44.png

**Here is my problem.**
When activity starts its look like in first screenshot. If i touch any element in listView, or scroll it (if there is a lot of elements) it baceme like in screenshot2. Exactly what i need. 
How can i take image like in scrennshot 2 in activity start?

I overrited method @Override public void onScroll(..) in OnScrollListener of  my listView, where i aplly all paddings:

```
    // int x = 30;
    for (int i = 0; i < visibleItemCount; ++i)
    {
        View v = listView.getChildAt(i);

        if (v != null)
        {


            LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rl);

            float sin = (float) (v.getTop() + v.getHeight() / 2 - centerOfCircle) / radius;
            double angle = Math.asin(sin);

            int x = (int) (-dXRow + radius * Math.cos(angle));

            if (x < 0)
                x = 0;

            Log.d("MN", "setPadding: " + x);

            rl.setPadding(x, 0, 0, 0);

        }
    }
```

Really sorry for my Engish

Answer (score 0):

You should set starting peddings in the getView() method of your listView's adapter. And then recompute them onScroll() as you need.

OnScroll method isnt invoked when the listView appear, only when you scroll it.

Comment: its invoked ater activity starts. And its work a little strange. For example, if i apply fixed padding 80, it will looke like this: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44444463/Screenshot_2013-02-28-15-20-47.png

So i need to rebuild me row view? invalidete() have no effect

Comment: Why dont you set needed paddings or margins in the getView() method?

Comment: I dont know how to get top distance of view. Is it possible?

Comment: You can try to use methods getTop() and getBottom() of the View class.